# Remove query string and redirect using mod rewrite syntax

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

What is the syntax to rewrite this

http://www.example.com/cart/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=8&products_id=22

to this?
http://www.example.com/class-registration

Note: RewriteBase has to be / because other rules depend on it.

Comment: Show what you have got so far

Answer (score 0):

The exact *and* working answer to your question is:

```
RewriteRule cart/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=8&products_id=22 class-registration [L]
```

But I'm pretty sure your question wasn't actually what you meant...